# Layer Slider Navigation Position

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am working on a website that uses Layer Slider. I am trying to position the navigation arrows as shown in image. But for anything I write I CSS, nothing affects look of navigation arrows.

Navigation is visible if you hover over image.

[image]

Forgive me as I can not post the code for same.

Website can be accessed [Here](http://addnectar.co.in/Polymers2/).

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
a.ls-nav-prev {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

a.ls-nav-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

If you use this instead of `top:50%` your arrows will be perfectly aligned verticaly. With `top:50%` they will be unaligned.

And next time please post a little code of what you've tried to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try using : absolute positioning on a.ls-nav-prev and a.ls-nav-next like

```
    a.ls-nav-prev,a.ls-nav-prev{
       position: absolute;
    }
```

Now for Prev arrow use "left:" and for next use "right:" properties

Answer (score 0):

In the same div than the slider, you can try something like this :

```
<div>
   <!-- Slider here -->
   <a href="#" class="left-arrow"><img src="arrow-left.png"/></a>
   <a href="#" class="right-arrow"><img src="arrow-right.png"/></a>
</div>
```

And on your css:

```
.left-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top : 50%
  left: 0px;
}

.right-arrow{
 position: absolute;
 top:50%
 right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.ls-nav-prev, a.ls-nav-next {
    margin-left: 0% !important;
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

a.ls-nav-next{
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some comments?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this way.

```css
.container{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
}

.slider{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#EEE;
}

.carouselController{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:10%;
    text-align:center;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-9px; /*Depends on your icon height*/
}
.leftContainer{
    left:0px;
}

.rightContainer{
    right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="leftContainer carouselController">
            <i><</i>
        </div>
        <div class="rightContainer carouselController">
            <i>></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```